# I used MPAndroidChart library in my app, How to give space between bars?

Tags: android, graphics, charts, mpandroidchart

Can you tell how to give space between the bars and fit to the screen.

Issue

I had reduced bar width with `chart.getLayoutParams().width=70`. my graph compressed and it is not looking good. I want to give space between them so that i will look good

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [spaceview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) to create space between the bars?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
chart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(1);
```

or follow the solution [proposed by PhilJay in the related GitHub issue](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/197):

> Space between individual bars:
>
> ```
> barDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(...);
> ```
>
> Space between DataSets:
>
> ```
> barData.setGroupSpace(...);
> ```
>
> Values in percent.

Comment: if I add multiple datasets it adds space between bars ad reduce the width of the bar

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest MpChart Library, you should use

```
            val data = BarData(dataSets)
            data.barWidth = 0.7f //bar width
            data.getGroupWidth(0f, 2f)//space between bars
```

Above code is in kotlin